# 'CharField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden' when passing initial value to a form's CharField which uses a TinyMCE widget

Tags: django, python-3.x, tinymce, django-tinymce

I'm setting up a site where users can create "lectures" which have a stylized lecture text. The style is facilitated by the TinyMCE plugin applied when filling out the `lecture_text` field when creating a lecture. Creating the lecture works fine, but I'd like this stylized text to already be in the lecture text area of the lecture update form. To my understanding, I can set the default content of the TinyMCE `CharField` with the `initial` argument. Here is my code right now:

**the editLecture HTML passes the lecture ID to the editLecture view**

```
...
<form method="post" action="{% url 'openvlab:editLecture' lecture_id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ lecture_form.as_p }}
    <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=re1omq7fkhbmtyijhb3xvx4cfhyl3op33zggwlqkmbt5swvp"></script>
    <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
    <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

**the editLecture view passes the lecture ID to the lecture update form**

```
def editLecture(request,id_string):
...
    lecture_form = LectureUpdateForm(lecture_id=id_string)
...
```

**the lecture update form**

```
class LectureUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        lecture_id=kwargs.pop("lecture_id")
        lecture = Lecture.objects.get(id__exact=lecture_id)
        super(LectureUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['lecture_text'].widget = forms.CharField(
                 widget=TinyMCEWidget(
                     attrs={'required': False, 'cols': 30, 'rows': 10},
                     ),  
                 initial=lecture.lecture_text # this is where I try to define the initial content of the editor
                 )

    class Meta:
        model = Lecture
        fields = ['lecture_title', 'lecture_description', 'lecture_text']
```

When trying to access the lecture editing page, however, I get an AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'. (If you need a more detailed traceback, let me know and I will provide it.)

I'm fairly new to Django, so I apologize if I missed something obvious or my code isn't following conventions; to my knowledge, this error isn't addressed in any of the other questions I've seen on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the widget to a Field object, which itself has a widget. Don't do that.

```
self.fields['lecture_text'] = forms.CharField(...)
#                          ^
```

However, this isn't the way to do any of this. You should be passing the `instance` attribute when initialising the form from the view, then you don't need to mess around with initial data at all.

```
lecture = Lecture.objects.get(id=id_string)
lecture_form = LectureUpdateForm(instance=lecture)
```

Comment: Oh, I thought I'd tried that but apparently one of the lines was off before. Thanks!